# AngularJS Dynamic Filtering not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat with two filters.  When i update one "uniqueFilter" via a button, the list does not update with my new filter.  Here's the HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="FooterController" class="bar bar-footer">
    <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="switchViewType('LOCATIONS')">Locations</button>
    <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="switchViewType('DEPARTMENTS')">Right</button>
    <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="switchViewType('CENTERS')">update</button>
  </div>

  <div class="list list-inset has-subheader-sbm"> 
    <label class="item item-input">
      <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="search" ng-model="query" placeholder="Search">
    </label>
  </div>

  <ion-content ng-controller="ListController" class="has-subheader-search-sbm">
    <ion-list>
        <a class='item item-icon-right' ng-repeat="item in directory | filter : type=uniqueFilter | filter : query" href="tel:{{item.phone}}">
          {{item.label1}}<br>
          {{item.label2}}
         <i class="icon ion-ios-information-outline"></i>
      </a>
    </ion-list>   
 </ion-content>
```

Here is my app.js code

```
appCtrl.controller('ListController', function($scope, $http) {

  var url =   'https://server/Ataglanceservice.svc/getDAAG';

  $http.get(url).then(function(resp) {

    // For JSON responses, resp.data contains the result
    $scope.data = resp.data
    $scope.directory = angular.fromJson($scope.data);
  }, function(err) {
   console.error('ERR', err);
  })

 $scope.uniqueFilter = 'DEPARTMENTS';
 //$scope.varView = 'LOCATIONS';

});

appCtrl.controller("FooterController", function($scope, $localStorage) {


$scope.switchViewType = function($viewType) {
  $scope.uniqueFilter = $viewType;
}

});
```

Can anyone tell me why my filtered list is not being updated?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scopes are different in each controller, each $scope.uniqueFilter point to different locations. A simple way to fix this is merge the controllers and just use 1 controller if possible, or make use of angular services (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), having the variable as a part of a service so it may be used across different controllers.

Comment: ok, I got it working!  I thought scope was available globally.  thanks for your help!